# Classic SF-Movie in which a man assembles a device from packages

Tags: story-identification, movie

I have a vague memory of a movie from the 50s or 60s (I’d say) in which a man receives over the time of weeks several packages of unknown origin with strange device parts it them.  Following an assembly chart, he then builds a device part by part (so that takes a certain amount of time in the story).

When it is finished, the device represents a connection to some alien species; either it allows communication or even traveling — I cannot recall.

I have a vague memory of a large upside-down triangle (▽) being part of the device; I think it was a display of some kind.

I’m pretty sure the movie was in black and white, but I wouldn’t bet on it.

I already scanned a lot of images on Google and tried finding it in the IMDb, but no success yet.

Does anybody happen to know the film?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This could be *[This Island Earth](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047577/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)*, a science fiction film from 1955.

The plot concerns aliens who come to Earth to recruit scientists to help them in their war. From an IMDB review:

> The film divides itself more or less clearly into two parts. In the
> first part, electronic genius and atomic power researcher, **Rex Reason,
> is challenged by an unknown source to build an interociter**. He
> successfully passes the test. **The interociter acts like a big,
> triangular TV** except that it has a self-destruct mechanism and can
> emit deadly rays that melt lead. When Reason turns it on, he is able
> to communicate with Exeter (Jeff Morrow), who describes himself as "a
> scientist like yourself." Morrow invites Reason to take a trip on a
> mysterious, pilot-less airplane, which he does. The plane lands at a
> fully equipped laboratory complex which houses a handful of the most
> famous scientists in the world. All of them seem to be working on the
> conversion of matter into energy. Morrow warns them not to discuss
> their work with each other and, in fact, the place is a bit like a
> fancy prison. Reason and another scientist, Faith Domergue, are
> spirited away in a space ship and the other scientists destroyed.

The "interociter" (see below) is a communication apparatus which the scientist has to build piece by piece, solving it like a puzzle. After completing it the scientist is transported to a UFO, and travels to the alien planet.

[image: The interociter from "This Island Earth"]

Comment: Thank you!  AAAAAnd, actually it’s on YouTube. :-D

Obviously there’s a lot more in the movie I didn’t remember at all.

Comment: Based on the novel by Raymond F. Jones, originally published as a series of three stories in *Thrilling Wonder Stories*: ["The Alien Machine"](https://archive.org/details/Thrilling_Wonder_Stories_v34n02_1949-06/page/n73/mode/2up), ["The Shroud of Secrecy"](https://archive.org/details/Thrilling_Wonder_Stories_v35n02_1949-12/page/n63/mode/2up), and ["The Greater Conflict"](https://archive.org/details/Thrilling_Wonder_Stories_v35n03_1950-02/page/n91/mode/2up).

Answer (score 9):

I believe this is [*This Island Earth*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047577/) (1955).

Quoting from the Wikipedia [plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Island_Earth#Plot):

> At the lab is an unusual substitute for the electronic condensers that he had ordered. Instead, he discovers instructions and parts to build a complex device called an "interocitor". Neither Meacham nor his assistant Joe Wilson have heard of such a device, but they immediately begin its construction. When they finish, a mysterious man named Exeter appears on the interocitor's screen and informs Meacham that he has passed a test. His ability to build the interocitor demonstrates that he is gifted enough to be part of Exeter's special research project.